# How to mount a volume to a Kubernetes Pod running a docker container from the Airflow host that triggers it using the KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, airflow

I have a DAG in airflow that uses the [KubernetesPodOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator/) and I am trying to get some files that are generated by the container running in the pod back to the airflow host. For development my host is a Docker container running an [airflow image](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) with a docker-desktop K8s cluster and for production I am using an AWS EC2 box with EKS.

```
volume_mount = VolumeMount('dbt-home',
                           mount_path=<CONTAINER_DIR>,
                           sub_path=None,
                           read_only=False)

volume_config= {
    'hostPath':
      {'path': <HOST_DIR>, 'type': 'DirectoryOrCreate'}
    }

volume = Volume(name="dbt-home", configs=volume_config)


dbt_run = KubernetesPodOperator(
                          namespace='default',
                          image=MY_IMAGE>,
                          cmds=["bash", "-cx"],
                          arguments=[command],
                          env_vars=MY_ENVIRONMENT,
                          volumes=[volume],
                          volume_mounts=[volume_mount],
                          name="test-run",
                          task_id="test-run-task",
                          config_file=config_file,
                          get_logs=True,
                          reattach_on_restart=True,
                          dag=dag
                          )
```

I tried using the hostPath type for the volume but i think that it refers to the host of the pod. I looked in the kubernetes documentation around volumes where I found the EmptyDir one which didnt work out either.

Comment: I think I can probably help since I use the PodOperator and mount volumes, but I don't really understand what you're asking.  So, you are spawning a pod to run your DAG, and what volume do you want mounted into it?

Comment: Hi @Howard_Roark Im spawning a pod from inside an Airflow DAG to run a task. I have Airflow hosted on EC2. Some log files are generated in the pod container by the task. I would like to get those log files back onto the Airflow host to be picked up by the next task.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you are asking how one task run in a pod can complete and write logs to a location that another task run in a pod can read when it starts.  It seems like you could do a few things.

1. You could just have your task that starts get the logs of the previous pod that completed via either `kubectl get logs` (ie- put kubectl into your task image and permission its service account to get the logs of pods in that namespace) or use the Kubernetes python API to get the logs.
2. You could mount a pvc into your initial Task at a certain location and write the logs there, and then when it completes, you can mount that same pvc into your next Task and it can read the logs from that location.  You could use ebs if it will only be mounted into one pod at a time, or you could use nfs if it will be mounted into many pods at a time.  Probably nfs would make sense so that you could share your logs across many Tasks in pods at once.
3. You can ship your logs to [Cloudwatch via fluentd](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-setup-logs.html).  Your task could then query Cloudwatch for the previous task's logs.  I think that shipping your logs to Cloudwatch is a good practice anyway, and so you may as well do that.

I am not sure if you are looking for a more airflow native way of doing this, but those are ideas that come to mind that would solve your problem.

Comment: I am rying to mount multiple volumes to KubernetesPodOperator, I am getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/airflow/report_configs'` for the second volumeMount. I believe the volumes and volumeMounts are the list type and would mount all volumes (each one with different pvc/pv) in the list. Adding more than one volume/volumeMount does not work. Any suggestions ??

Comment: Ya you should be able to do that. You can see the spec here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator/index.html

Comment: One question. When we mention the volumes and volumeMounts for the KubernetesPodOperator, does it create one or do we need to create it prior to using it for KubernetesPodOperator ?? I created one first and then tried to mount it but still seeing `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/airflow/report_configs'`. Also, the volume in question is not mounted anywhere else..

Comment: config 
`volume = [ Volume(name='volume1', configs={'persistentVolumeClaim': {'claimName': 'volume_claim_1'}}),
            Volume(name='volume2', configs={'persistentVolumeClaim': {'claimName': 'volume_claim_2'}}) ]
volume_mount = [ VolumeMount('volume1',mount_path='/data/airflow/',sub_path=None,read_only=False),
                            VolumeMount('volume2',mount_path='/kubeop/airflow/',sub_path=None,read_only=False)]`

Comment: I am not sure if you are following the KubernetesPodOperator spec with your syntax there bc it's hard to read in the comments.  You could try following this person's example: https://varlogdiego.com/airflow-kubernetes-operator

Regarding your other question, you would create the pvc in advance and then reference in the Volume definition of your spec, and then pass it in to be mounted at a given path